# What is the source of google webmaster tools' data?

Tags: google-search-console

Where does google webmaster tools get all it's data from? Is it paired with google analytics etc or is it purely crawlers and searches it display?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pulled directly from crawls and searches and may contain different information compared to google analytics. You can read more information in the [Google Webmaster Tools FAQ](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769)